# How to combine columns of different excel files and renaming the column with the name of the initial file using R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, export, reshape2, r-xlsx

I have 96 different Excel files in a folder that all contain one single column, which looks approximately like this, whereby the uppermost line is the name of the Excel file:

```
A1.xlsx
Distance
245
534
142
6342
634
4343
2323
1123
666

A2.xlsx
Distance
2453
2452
4434
3456
6754
```

However, it would like to have one single .xlsx file, where all the separate files are copied into a new column side by side containing the name of the source file as a header for the column. Furthermore, the current header should be removed. So, it should look like this then:

```
A1     A2     ...    Cn
245    2453   ...    ...
534    2452   ...
142    4434   ...
6342   3456   ...
634    6754   ...
4343          ...
2323          ...
1123
666
```

So far, I the following code:

```
fileList <-file.path(dir(path = ".", pattern = "^[a-zA-Z].+$", full.names = TRUE), "*.xlsx")
load_if_exists <-function(filename, ...) {
  tryCatch(
    suppressWarnings(read.table(filename, ...)),
    error = function(x) tibble(NA)
  )
}

fileList <- list.files(".", "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)

listData <- lapply(fileList, read.table)

names(listData) <- gsub(".xlsx","",basename(fileList))

bind_rows(listData, .id = "FileName") %>%
  group_by(FileName) %>%
  mutate(rowNum = row_number()) %>%
  dcast(rowNum~FileName, value.var = "V1") %>%
  select(-rowNum) %>%
  write.xlsx(file="Result.xlsx")
```

With this code, a new file is generated, but the data is not available. Furthermore, there was also no error code.

Could please anybody help me solving this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are those actual Excel xlsx files that you are loading with `read.table()`? It can't work as `read.table()` expects a text file in table format,  but it should throw an error for sure.

Comment: I edited my answer so that the output is as you specified @Hotshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in with just a few steps - note, to combine them side-by-side you need to ensure they all have the same number of rows. So (1) import the data, (2) find the max number of rows in all the imported excel files, and (3) assign `NA` (or `""` if you prefer) to the data frames that are shorter than that (4) combine them all (here, using `do.call`):

```
flpth <- "your_filepath_here"

fileList <- list.files(flpth, ".xlsx", full.names = TRUE)

listData <- lapply(fileList, readxl::read_excel)

maxLength <- max(unlist(lapply(listData, nrow)))

lengthList <- lapply(listData, \(x){ 
  if(nrow(x) < maxLength) x[(nrow(x)+1):maxLength,] <- NA
  x})

allData <- do.call(data.frame, lengthList)

writexl::write_xlsx(allData, path = paste0(flpth, "new_file.xlsx"))
```

Output:

```
    A1.xlsx  A2.xlsx
1  Distance Distance
2       245     2453
3       534     2452
4       142     4434
5      6342     3456
6       634     6754
7      4343     <NA>
8      2323     <NA>
9      1123     <NA>
10      666     <NA>
```

[image]

Comment: Or not? Not sure if my edits disappeared or got deleted?

Comment: @jpsmith, thank you very much! This already helps a lot! The columns are combined really nicely, but the header is still called "Distance" instead of the file name (e.g., A7). Could you help me with this?

Comment: @Hotshot - see if the edit works?

Comment: @Nova - thanks so much for helping out. In this specific case, the edits you made were too far off from the original code, and included approachs and packages that extended beyond what I intended so they got reverted. When I use `writexl::write_xlsx` it exports the header appropriately. I've added this into the answer. Thanks again and happy coding!

Comment: Yeah, I can see that - base vs tidyverse. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @jpsmith, thanks a lot! But unfortunately, it still looks the same and first row still just shows Distance, Distance.2, Distance.3, Distance.4,..., Distance.95.

Comment: I was now able to solve the problem by just renaming the headers manually using the following code: 
headernames <- Sys.glob( "*.xlsx" )
allData <- setNames(allData, headernames)
Thank you very much again for your great help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working in a project and the folder you are looking for files in is named "excelfiles".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)


# List data available for processing ----

files <- list.files("excelfiles/", full.names = TRUE,
                    recursive = TRUE, pattern = "*.xlsx", ignore.case = TRUE)

filesdb <- tibble(filename = files)

head(filesdb)

# extract information about each table from the filenames using the "word" function
filesdb <- filesdb |> 
  mutate(ID = word(word(basename(filename), 1, 1, sep = "/"), 1, 1, sep = "\\."))

# make a vector (tempfiles) to use in a function below containing the filenames & ID
tempfiles <- filesdb$filename
IDS <- filesdb$ID
tempfiles <- set_names(tempfiles, IDS)

head(tempfiles)

# write a little function to extract data from each table
import_files <- function(file) {
  read_xlsx(file, col_names = TRUE, skip = 1)
} 


# Extract the data ----

# This next bit will take a while, depending on the number of files.
# If you'd like to try a few first to make certain it's working, test it on a smaller subset; 
# e.g.,  tempfiles[1:5]
tempdf <- map_df(tempfiles, import_files, .id = "IDS") %>% 
  group_by(IDS) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = IDS, values_from = Distance, values_fill = NA) %>% 
  select(-row)
```

Output

```
tempdf
# A tibble: 9 × 2
     A1    A2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   245  2453
2   534  2452
3   142  4434
4  6342  3456
5   634  6754
6  4343    NA
7  2323    NA
8  1123    NA
9   666    NA
```

Comment: when I run the code, the error message following error message appears:

Error in `pivot_wider()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Distance` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Hmmm... if you run `import_files` on one file, e.g., `import_files("excelfiles/A1.xlsx")` the column name in the output df should be `Distance`  - is it? The script works for me with data set up as you described in your question.